# How to recover closed output window in netbeans?

Tags: netbeans, window, output, recover

It often happens to me that I want to clear the current output window by using the context menu, but instead of hitting the `Clear` entry, I accidently hit the `Close` entry (which is directly below `Clear`).

How can I get that output window back!?

Via Window/Output/Output I only get the container tab for all output windows. How can I reopen the output window of a currently running application?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

In the right bottom edge there are information about NetBeans updates. Left to it, there's the tasks running (building, running application etc). Click on it, right click the process you want and select `Show Output`.

Comment: Hi, Yes, I found what you mean. But unfortunately it is always deactivated (greyed out). No matter whether the output window is still visible or already closed. Do I miss something? I tried it with Netbeans 7.3.

Comment: Well, I tried in NetBeans 7.3 and 7.0. Both work for me. Could not reproduce your problem here. Sorry.

Comment: I played around a bit and it seems that it does not work with maven projects. With an ant project it works well.

Comment: It could be. Only tested with Ant.

Comment: IMHO, this is a bug, as it should work under maven.  I have opened a bug report https://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=233924 will be interesting to see if they can fix.  You might want to vote for it if you agree this is an issue

Answer (score 46):

Here is solution

1. First go to service window which is next tab to project tab...
2. then right click on  apache tomcat
3. click view  server log and view server output

Comment: It is desabled! the solution is http://stackoverflow.com/a/27820775/1583946

Answer (score 33):

try  Window--> Reset Windows in netbean
Caution: be aware, that all your windows settings are away after that!

Comment: I had the same problem and only the reset windows method worked for me, neither the ctrl+4 nor any other method reseted the output window.

Comment: Worked for me. None of other options were working for me.

Answer (score 32):

I had this same issue recently and none of the other fixes worked.  I got it to show finally by switching to the "Services" tab, right-clicking on "Apache Tomcat or TomEE" and clicking "Restart".

Comment: This should be the accepted answer, as sometimes the "view server output" context menu entry is grayed out for no reason.

Comment: *FINALLY*!! Thank you!
Still a bug in Netbeans 8.2. But it has been so long since it happened that I'd forgotten what to do!!

Answer (score 20):

Go to the ***window*** tab: Then click on ***Output***. This will allow you to place it anywhere on the screen. Or just use ***ctrl+4***

Answer (score 11):

Go to Server tab and Right Click you will see the View Output Log.

***Netbeans --> Your Server --> RightClick --> View Output***

[image]

Answer (score 8):

In NetBeans 7.4,
Under Window menu, click on "Reset Window".
Then NetBeans will disappear and reappear.
At last, after it reappears, click on "Output" under Window menu.

Answer (score 7):

Go to window tab - reset windows  -  run your program. -  then right click on bottom of the tab where program running

Comment: Thank you! Nothing else seemed to bring the Output panel back; I can only guess that it was accidentally hidden in a weird way such that `Window -> Output` and the like were "showing" it but I still could not see it. After "reset windows" it came back.

Answer (score 3):

Right click on Apache Tomcat under Services window. Stop the server, then start it again...both log and output window will reappear

Answer (score 3):

Just go through "View" and select IDE Log. it will show the output.

Answer (score 2):

If you run the server in normal mode you can recover the log by restarting the main project in debug mode. It seems that NB opens a new server log when the server run mode changes.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to see three windows along with Log 
Then go to windows on `NetBeans` then `output` and click `NetBeans->windows->output`.
Next go to service next to you project select server right click on it select server log and server output `NetBeans->service(next to you project)->server->View server log` and view service output.

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same problem. Currently I am using the version 8.1, First of all go to the window tab, that is just before the tab help. Click on window and there click reset "Reset Window", after that in the bottom right click on the tab where your project runs, right click and select show output.

Answer (score 1):

shorter way:
1-Alt + Shift + R
2-Ctrl + 4
second way:(in menus of netBeans)
1-go to window tab
2-go to IDE tools
3-click on Test Result
4-again in window tab click on Output

Answer (score 1):

I found output option in window Menu. 
[image]

Answer (score 0):

in Netbeans 7.4 try Window -> Output OR Ctrl + 4

Answer (score 0):

Easy way, just write some wrong code and Run > Build it will show the error in output window.

I tried all of the above but no success, just this one worked.

Answer (score 0):

Servers---AT---right click---start in debugging mode

Comment: Don't just post answer only to get up vote. Its a serious platform and you can't get likes here, it's not facebook. You are answering this question after 8 years, but your answer is just a one liner. Please read carefully before posting answer https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer