# How can I see the output console result in Netbeans?

Tags: java, netbeans

I am a beginner studying Java using NetBeans. I created my first class and some simple code:

```
public class suju {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        System.out.print("hello word");
    }
}
```

Why don't I see any result when I click `run`? I am supposed to see `hello world` but nothing like this is shown.
Only a message `BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 0 seconds)`

Unfortunately, I can't post images yet to better present the problem I am facing.

Comment: Does this question help you? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15835888/how-to-recover-closed-output-window-in-netbeans

Comment: You can upload your image to an external image hosting site and include the link in your question. Users with higher reputation could then review and add the image to your post.

Comment: Since now you have at least 10 reputation points you should be able to add links to your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to right click on the class file on the left panel then choose run option

Answer (score 0):

Mine was doing the same.

I went to java.com and downloaded java again- it then prompted me to uninstall all out-if-date updates.

When I ran it again it was working.