# Jsoup and Translate Google in java

Tags: java, netbeans, jsoup

[image: screenshot]

I do not understand is why I get nothing on stout?

Comment: That's just Grammer check

Comment: How exactly are you trying to run this code? It looks like you ended up with only building/compiling it instead of running it.

Comment: Most probably duplicate of [how i can see the output console result in netbeans](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23323170/how-i-can-see-the-output-console-result-in-netbeans).

Comment: I want to get the results as "How are you" must do?

Comment: Question wasn't "what are you trying to do", but "how are you trying to run this code" because this step seems to be where problem is. Anyway did you visit question linked in my previous comment? Did you try running your code in a way described there?