# Netbeans 12.4 Tomcat 10 "View Server Output" grayed out

Tags: java, output, netbeans-12, tomcat10

I'm developing a Java web application using netbeans 12.4 and tomcat 10.
When I try to debug i see in the output window only the output of the compilation and the output of the Tomcat Server log, while the windows of the server output is missing.
I see on the popup menu that comes up right-clicking the tomcat server icon in the services tab, that the "View Server output" is disabled and i did'nt find a way to activate it and make the "System.out.println" visible.

Sometimes when i start the application, the windows i speaking about comes up and also all the entry in the services popup menu are active, but i don't understand how
this happens and how I can make it working when id does not.

I Googled this situation but i found only a similar problem with netbeans 7 dated 2013.

Can anybody help me?

[image: menu showing "view server output" disabled]

Answer (score 1):

It should be enough to restart the Tomcat server (I tried just now with Netbeans 12.4 on MacOS): just right-click on "Apache Tomcat or TomEE" and select "Restart".

Reference: https://stackoverflow.com/a/27820775/7907339

Comment: It seems that the problem was that during Tomcat Installation I did'nt configure the Shutdown port in the Server.xml to 8005 but I left the -1 proposed by the Installation Application.